# NodeJS client library for riak

Tags: node.js, riak, riak-js

I am starting a project that will use riak with nodejs. I see number of community supported libraries in nodejs for riak in basho site -- http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/libraries/#Basho-Supported-Libraries .
Can anybody point me to any research or experience with any of these and specific advantage / disadvantage faced while using any of these libraries ?
I shall do my research in parallel and will update the group with results.

Answer (score 1):

Basho released the official client today:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/basho-riak-client